# How to use not pure-JS (C++) Node.js modules in Cloud9IDE?

Tags: node.js, cloud9-ide

I am developing Node.js application in Cloud9IDE and I problem using module (like [node-expat](https://github.com/astro/node-expat)) in Cloud9IDE.

If it was pure-JavaScript module, there shouldn't be problem, but modules that compiles C++ code for interaction with NodeJS...

I wounder if there is possibility to use/run modules that compiles C++ code in Cloud9IDE. May be you have some experience with this?

Thanks for any feedback!

Cheers,
Milan

Comment: Should be a question on the cloud9 mailing list really or #cloud9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now Cloud9 IDE blocks binary node modules for security reasons. Right now there is now way to use them. We (the cloud9 team) are discussing ways to enable binary modules e.g. by whitelisting trusted ones.

Comment: Ok, thats true what you wrote but on the other side I have possibility to run Cloud9IDE on my server and use it. So this is one way how to use modules that compiles C++ code... It could be better if you wrote that I could work in Cloud9IDE with enabled binary modules only if I install it alone on my own server. However, thanks for the info!